# Integrating reciprocals of functions with known antiderivatives

Tags: calculus

If
$$\int_{}^{} f(x)\,dx$$
is known, is there a way to directly find
$$\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{f(x)}\,dx$$

Comment: Not really, no.  Sorry.  Take $f(x)=x$, then you get $x^2/2$ and $\ln x$, respectively.

Comment: For example, the integral of $\frac{x}{e^x}$, that is, of $xe^{-x}$, is nice and simple, but the integral of $\frac{e^x}{x}$ is not an elementary function.

Comment: The motivation was very natural which puzzled me for long time to disprove.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x)$ in a power series. Let 
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, x^{n}
\end{align}
then it can be seen that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{a_{0}} - \frac{a_{1}}{a_{0}^{2}} \, x + \frac{a_{1}^{2} - a_{2}}{a_{0}^{3}} \, x^{2} + \cdots
\end{align}
Integration of each shows
\begin{align}
\int f(x) \, dx &= a_{0} x + \frac{a_{1}}{2} \, x^{2} + \frac{a_{2}}{3} \, x^{3} + \cdots \\
\int \frac{dx}{f(x)} &= \frac{x}{a_{0}} - \frac{a_{1}}{2 \, a_{0}^{2}} \, x^{2} + \frac{a_{1}^{2} - a_{2}}{3 \, a_{0}^{3}} \, x^{3} + \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: +1, nice answer, but one could argue if this is a way to "directly find" the integral.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Without knowing what $f(x)$ is it is hard to directly evaluate the integrals. The display given here is a way of how different the integral evaluations are.

Comment: You are right, of course, and it is good that you made the motivation explicit. As I said, nice answer!